# loading from a .txt file, no file directory

Tags: python, load, tkinter, save

When i run this code i get an error saying the file does not exist, i have created the file and linked back to them by copying the directory from the save part. I can also see the file and have triple checked the name etc but it still won't work can someone help.

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
master= Tk()
master.geometry('500x500+0+0')



def print_value(val):
    print ("c1="+str (c1v.get()))
    print ("c2="+str(c2v.get()))


c1v=DoubleVar()
c2v=DoubleVar()


c1 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value, variable =c1v)
c1.grid(row=1,column=1)
c2 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value, variable =c2v)
c2.grid(row=1,column=2)


def func():
    pass
    file1 = open("C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx/preset_test.txt")
    val1, val2 = (x.split("=")[1] for x in file1)
    c1.set(val1)
    c2.set(val2)
    file1.close()


def record():

    save_path = 'C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx'
    name_of_file = ("preset_test ")
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
    file1 = open(completeName , "w")
    toFile = ("c1="+str (c1.get())+ "\n""c2="+str(c2.get()))
    file1.write(toFile)
    file1.close()
    master.mainloop()

rec=Button(master, text="Record",width=20, height=10, bg='Red', command=record)
rec.grid(row=2, column=1)

load=Button(master, text="Load",width=20, height=10, bg='gold',command=func)
load.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

the error is-

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
     seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)   File "C:\Python33\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
     raise Empty queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Josh Bailey\Desktop\save test.py", line 24, in func
     file1 = open("C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx/preset_test.txt") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]
No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx/preset_test.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `func`, you specify the filepath as being:

```
C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx/preset_test.txt
```

However, your `record` function makes it to be:

```
C:/Users/Josh Bailey/Desktop/pi_dmx/preset_test .txt
#                   Note the extra space here--^
```

Because of this, Python will not be able to find the file.

---

To fix the problem, remove the space on this line in `record`:

```
name_of_file = ("preset_test ")
#                     here--^
```

Now record will create the filepath to be what it should.

---

Also, that `pass` inside of `func` should not be there.  It does nothing.

Comment: perfect thank you, and yes i forgot to delete the pass when i added int in earlier

Answer (score 0):

You're on Windows right? Replace the slashes with backslashes, \, and add a "r" infront of the string, like this:

```
file1 = open(r"C:\Users\Josh Bailey\Desktop\pi_dmx\preset_test.txt")
```

Hope this works

Comment: Actually, Python can use filepaths with forward slashes just fine on Windows.